# what is the output of shap_values & explainer.expected_value ?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm running the shap on XGBClassifier model and trying to understand the output.
my code :

```
params2 = {'n_estimators': 100,
               'learning_rate': 0.5,
               'seed': 0,
               'subsample': 0.8,
               'n_jobs': 50,
               'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
               'objective': 'binary:logistic',
               'max_depth': 10,
               'min_child_weight': 300,
               'gamma': 2,
               'max_delta_step': 6
               }

estimator = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params2)
mapper = DataFrameMapper([(i, None) if j != 'object' and j != 'bool' else (i,
                          [CategoricalDomain(
                           missing_value_treatment="as_value",
                           invalid_value_treatment="as_missing",
                           missing_value_replacement=
                           train_x[i].value_counts().idxmax(),
                           invalid_value_replacement=
                           train_x[i].value_counts().idxmax()),
                           LabelEncoder()])
                           for i, j in zip(train_x.columns.values, train_x.dtypes.values)],
                           input_df=True, df_out=True)

pmml_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("mapper", mapper),("classifier", estimator)])
pmml_pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y.as_matrix())
train_x_encode = pmml_pipeline.named_steps['mapper'].fit_transform(train_x)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(pmml_pipeline.named_steps['classifier'])
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(train_x_encode)
print explainer.expected_value
```

According to my understanding, `explainer.expected_value` suppose to return an array of size two and `shap_values` should return two matrixes, one for the positive value and one for the negative value as this is a classification model.
but `explainer.expected_value` actually returns one value and `shap_values` returns one matrix

My questions are :

1. What am I missing, why isn't the output from shap is two dimensional like the model output.
2. if `explainer.expected_value` should be one dimensional so what it stands for (I expected to get two values - average predicted probability to 1 ,average predicted probability to two)
3. regarding the `shap_values` matrix: for categorical variable, can I average all shap values for each variable value and say that the average I get is the impact of this value on the target variable ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason I can think about is that your ground-truth labels have only one unique value. In this case `explainer.expected_value` is not an array but a number. Also, `shap_values` contains only one matrix.

1. You are missing nothing, if my assumption about the true labels is correct. Take a look at the source code, for example [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/_linear.py)
2. In this case it will be the expected value for the unique label/class you have in your labels
3. I am not really sure if I understand you correctly but as I understood you don't need to average the values